# Assets.at outside play/project folder

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have my static files in a directory outside of the play/project folder. But this doesn't work at all:

`GET /  controllers.Assets.at(path="../../angular-app/", file="index.html")`

Is there a way to make this work? (I really don't want to move the static files inside the `public/` folder.)

Play version: 2.3.7

Comment: The assets need to get packaged with the application, so no. That doesn't mean you can't serve assets from outside that directory, just probably not with the `Assets` controller.

Answer (score 1):

Use frontend HTTP server for serving these files and then write paths manually (not via `Assets.at()` method. like:

```
<img src="/my-folder-controlled-with-nginx/images/image.png" />
```